# function return type decision

Tags: c, function, return

Little micro-controller (arduino) for my home automation project listens to a pin high low status change.  When the pin status changes,

**function** is called like below:

```
  NotSureYet  sendMessageOnPinChange(8, "You turned on the kitchen lights ");
```

**returns**

- The function will check if it was invoked with *first parameter* being an *integer* range from 0 to 16, else it returns 'error' *(like: you should use a number between ...)*
- the function checks if the second param is of type char * (a string), else it returns an error *(like: the message is not a string)*
- the function also returns if the message was 'sent' correctly or not

**Question**
What would be the return type NotSureYet?

While once it returns "Message Sent success", which is NOT an error, and any other case it returns "error integer" or "error Message" or ...
So I am not looking for error checking, I am looking for the return type of 'NOT_SURE_YET'

Comment: You can't check types at runtime in C.

Comment: There's good reason for why you see so many project actually do this :P because C is very low level you have to build everything yourself including complex error checking.

Comment: Also @melpomene is right about compile-time vs runtime checking. Any range checking etc. would also have to be built by you :P

Comment: @Ahmed Masud: so how would you return from this function, would you return your own 'error' struct?

Comment: @hewi typically ints are still used in C because int's are small and stay in CPU registers. You could for example encode your errors in bits in an int and then have a string of error messages to go along with it. This is what errno/perror do ... Just follow that same recipe. As a matter of fact you can `augment` perror/strerror and utilize errno. That way any system errors show up regularly and your own errors show up in addition. If you want to capture complex data create a reporting structure that captures more info. IMHO keep it simple, error handling should not cause errors itself. :)

Comment: i think you can change whatever you want, once indicated duplicate, there is no way back :)

Comment: or I am missing the point of how "function return type decision" == "Error handling in C code "

Answer (score 0):

You would return a struct with two members.

```
typedef struct {
    const char *error_str;
    bool success;
} NotSureYet;
```

Note: I haven't tried to compile this but it should work.

Comment: so basically I need to create my own error return type, are there templates, guidelines, best practices?